# Xamarin forms ToolBar Item place in center of action bar and display notification near that item

Tags: c#, xaml, notifications, xamarin.forms

I am trying to put my toolbar image.png item in the center of the action bar, but unfortunately, Xamarin doesn't have such an alignment properties. Maybe I can override somehow, or maybe there is any other approach for that?

Current view:
[image]

Here is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MF.Parking;assembly=jhjujty"
                  x:Class="jhjujty.MainPage" Padding="20,40,5,5" 
          MasterBehavior="Popover" BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
      <ToolbarItem x:Name="Provider"
               Text="ggfdgdfg: " Priority="0" Order="Primary" >
      </ToolbarItem>
      <ToolbarItem x:Name="Click"
             Icon="dropDown.png" Priority="1" Order="Primary" >
      </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <MasterDetailPage.Master BackgroundColor="White">
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage BackgroundColor="White">
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:Page3 x:Name="Page" />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And here is piece of MainPage class:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    PPPage page;
    public PProvider SelectedProvider { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
        {
            Icon = "image.png"
        });

        Page3.gfdgfdgfdgfdgdfg();

        Click.Clicked += (sender, e) => { OpenWindow(); };
        Provider.Clicked += (sender, e) => { OpenWindow(); };
    }
```

I was trying to create toolbar item in XAML, but then I thought maybe C# will have more properties, but unfortunately there isn't. Also, I would like to add BadgeValue near that image. Would it be possible to do it? It will look like notification near that image.